# Table not showing even after doing RefreshDatabaseWindow

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ado

I am trying to pull in some columns from an excel sheet (actually containing 156 columns x 16k rows) into a dynamically created table using "SELECT (columns, , ,) INTO TEMPO FROM ...", but though the code executes, the table does not appear in navigation pane. Sometimes, it gives error on .Execute (StrSQL) line that "Table already exists".

I have tried checking the table if it exists, then delete it OR in hidden Sys tables, but it does not show up. As you can see the commented code, I have also tried **RefreshDatabaseWindow** as well as **CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh** but table still doesn't show up.

I had also tried **DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet** to pull in worksheet data, but it was resulting in "Record too large" error. Also with **DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet**, one cannot select non-adjacent columns. Also the columns may not be in same sequence in some other excel sheet extract.

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "TEMPO", FileSelector(), True, "Soaps$"
```

Can anyone help me with rectifying the code?

```vb
    Sub grabData()

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim objCon As Object
    Dim objRS As Object
    Dim conStr As String

'    On Error Resume Next
'    strSQL = "DROP TABLE TEMPO;"
'    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
'    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TEMPO"
    If IsTableExists("TEMPO") Then CurrentDb.Execute "DROP TABLE TEMPO", dbFailOnError

    Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL = "SELECT "
    strSQL = strSQL & "[GTIN],[PVID],[Version Date],[Languages on Pack],[Description],[Brand],[Features],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[Other Information],[Trademark Information],[Safety Warnings],[Country],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[Manufacturers Address],[Importer Address],[Return To],[Web Address],[Recycling],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[Recycling Other Text],[Dimensions: Captured Height (mm)],[Gross Weight (g)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[Ingredients],[Nutrition],[Per100 Energy (kJ)],[Per100 Energy (kcal)],[Per100 Fat (g)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[Per100 thereof Sat Fat (g)],[Per100 Carbohydrates (g)],[Per100 thereof Total Sugar (g)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[Per100 Protein (g)],[Per100 Fibre (g)],[Per100 Sodium (g)],[Per100 Salt (g)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing PortionType],[PerServing Energy (kJ)],[PerServing Energy (kcal)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing Fat (g)],[PerServing thereof Sat Fat (g)],[PerServing Carbohydrates (g)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing thereof Total Sugar (g)],[PerServing Protein (g)],[PerServing Fibre (g)],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing Salt (g)],[Net Content] "
    strSQL = strSQL & " INTO TEMPO "
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Soaps$]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY [GTIN],[PVID],[Version Date]"

'    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Database=" & FileSelector() & "].[Drinks$]"


    With objCon
        .provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FileSelector() & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;"""
        .Open
        Set objRS = .Execute(strSQL)
    End With

    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
'    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh

    Set objRS = Nothing
    Set objCon = Nothing

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Here is the function to check if table exists or not.

```vb
Function IsTableExists(TblName As String) As Boolean
    IsTableExists = False
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & TblName & "' And Type In (1,4,6)")) Then IsTableExists = True
End Function
```

Here is the function to select file and path name.

```vb
Function FileSelector() As String
    Dim dlg As Object

    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(3) 'msoFileDialogFilePicker
    With dlg
        .Title = "Select the Excel data extract to import"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx", 1

        If .Show = -1 Then
            FileSelector = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            End
        End If
    End With

    Set dlg = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: As far as I see, you are not creating new table in MS Access. All your SQL is run in Excel connection. Why is the very important line that queries Excel from Access commented out? Even interesting is the `INTO` SQL command did not err out when run on workbook.

Comment: Aha, got it! Thanks @Parfait for pointing me in the right direction. I have added this in the query now:     **strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0;Database=" & FileSelector() & "].[Soaps$]"**
. The only problem is if i want to include all 156 columns, i get "Record too large" error, if I use this: 
**" SELECT * INTO TEMPO FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0;Database=" & FileSelector() & "].[Soaps$]"**. Any idea how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove any ADO connection to Excel workbook and run the Excel connection inline to your MS Access query. Then, execute the make-table query with `CurrentDb.Execute`:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT "
strSQL = strSQL & "[GTIN],[PVID],[Version Date],[Languages on Pack],[Description],[Brand],[Features],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Other Information],[Trademark Information],[Safety Warnings],[Country],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Manufacturers Address],[Importer Address],[Return To],[Web Address],[Recycling],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Recycling Other Text],[Dimensions: Captured Height (mm)],[Gross Weight (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Ingredients],[Nutrition],[Per100 Energy (kJ)],[Per100 Energy (kcal)],[Per100 Fat (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Per100 thereof Sat Fat (g)],[Per100 Carbohydrates (g)],[Per100 thereof Total Sugar (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Per100 Protein (g)],[Per100 Fibre (g)],[Per100 Sodium (g)],[Per100 Salt (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing PortionType],[PerServing Energy (kJ)],[PerServing Energy (kcal)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing Fat (g)],[PerServing thereof Sat Fat (g)],[PerServing Carbohydrates (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing thereof Total Sugar (g)],[PerServing Protein (g)],[PerServing Fibre (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[PerServing Salt (g)],[Net Content] "
strSQL = strSQL & " INTO TEMPO "
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0;Database=" & FileSelector() & "].[Soaps$]"
strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY [GTIN],[PVID],[Version Date]"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

---

As for the error, *Record is too large*, see this MS Office [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/111304/prb-vb-record-too-large-when-add-or-update-record-2k) which indicates a limit placed by design:

> The following error is the result when you Update or Add a Text field
>   in a table and the total record size exceeds about 2000 bytes for all
>   fields combined (not counting Memo fields)

With unicode compression, this per record limit can be increased to 4,000 bytes (4K).

For you, with N=156 columns, just having more than 13 characters per cell in any one row, you can reach this record limit. Possibly, you have a field(s) with large amount of text data which you can try ignoring in `SELECT` clause. Alternatively, try normalizing your table design in one-to-many with the many *PerServing* and *Per100* fields as they tend to repeat. See below example:

```vb
UniqueID | ContentType                | ContentValue
-------------------------------------------------------
1001     | Per100 Energy (kJ)         | 1000
1001     | Per100 Energy (kcal)       | 750
1001     | Per100 Fat (g)             | 250
1001     | Per100 thereof Sat Fat (g) | 20
1001     | Per100 Carbohydrates (g)   | 1400
...
```

With this schema, you will need to run two make-table imports for *Temp* holding distinct records and *ContentTable* for multiple-item records where *UniqueID* links the two tables. One is the simple `SELECT` query for indicator fields and the other an iterative append query for content type fields. Later, you can always run a [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) to reshape the long format back to wide as Excel workbook has it. Do note any Access table/query has a limit of 255 columns.

**TEMPO**

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT "
strSQL = strSQL & "[GTIN],[PVID],[Version Date],[Languages on Pack],[Description],[Brand],[Features],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Other Information],[Trademark Information],[Safety Warnings],[Country],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Manufacturers Address],[Importer Address],[Return To],[Web Address],[Recycling],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Recycling Other Text],[Dimensions: Captured Height (mm)],[Gross Weight (g)],"
strSQL = strSQL & "[Ingredients],[Nutrition] "
strSQL = strSQL & " INTO TEMPO "
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0;Database=" & FileSelector() & "].[Soaps$]"
strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY [GTIN],[PVID],[Version Date]"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

**ContentTable**

```vb
...
Dim var As Variant
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim strFileName As String

strFileName = FileSelector() 

' FIRST CONTENT TYPE TO CREATE TABLE
strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT [UniqueIDColumn] As UniqueID,"
strSQL = strSQL & "        'Per100 Energy (kJ)' As ContentType,"
strSQL = strSQL & "        [Per100 Energy (kJ)] As ContentValue"
strSQL = strSQL & " INTO ContentTable"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0;Database=" & strFileName & "].[Soaps$]"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

' SECOND TYPE AND ONWARD TO APPEND TO TABLE
For Each var in Array("Per100 Protein (g)", "Per100 Fibre (g)", "Per100 Sodium (g)", "Per100 Salt (g)", _
                      "PerServing PortionType", "PerServing Energy (kJ)", "PerServing Energy (kcal)", _
                      "PerServing Fat (g)", "PerServing thereof Sat Fat (g)", "PerServing Carbohydrates (g)", _
                      "PerServing thereof Total Sugar (g)", "PerServing Protein (g)", "PerServing Fibre (g)", _
                      "PerServing Salt (g)", "Net Content")

     strSQL = "PARAMETERS [ContentTypeParam] TEXT;"
     strSQL = strSQL & " INSERT INTO ContentTable (UniqueID, ContentType, ContentValue)"
     strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT [UniqueIDColumn], [ContentTypeParam], [" & var & "]"
     strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0;Database=" & strFileName & "].[Soaps$]"

     Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
     qdef![ContentTypeParam] = var    
     qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

     Set qdef = Nothing
Next var
```